# Custom success callback when posting from jQuery to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, webforms, callback, google-sheets-api

I have an application that requires posting form data from a web site to a Google Docs spreadsheet.

Normally Google spreadsheet posts do a redirect to a google thank-you page.

I need to hijack this redirect and put up my own thank-you success page. Or keep them on the submit page with a little success alert.

This jsFiddle (using Malsup jquery.forms.js) works great except for the sucess callback..

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn3rg/)

[Target spreadsheet here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Av26P_P3GJxAdEdDTl9qWlRLdmhUd1hSRlgzOGZQUlE&hl=en_US&authkey=CKGqpOcP)

Any and all thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there an actual API for this? You should use the actual GData API instead of basically screen-scraping. You're just asking to get your application blocked.

Comment: yes.. I would like a chance to work with google oAuth Playground, etc.. but in this case the data really is going into google spreadsheet.. the only hack is to hijack the callback for our own thank-you.. but your point about google not liking that is well taken

Comment: No, I'm literally saying there's an official Google API for working with Google Docs, including spreadsheets. If you're going to programmatically do anything with Google Spreadsheets you *need* to use the official API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution here that seems to work very well so far..

[Customizing Google Docs Form For Email Validation Using Free jQuery Script](http://www.2webvideo.com/video-production/customizing-google-docs-form-for-email-validation-with-free-jquery-script)

run the form code on any web page..  post goes to Google Spreadsheet...   call back directs to custom local confirm page.. not google thank you page...  probably could use some more error handling